# How to round QToolTip corners with CSS and QT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, tooltip

Please post some working example. The one below makes two borders: the rectangular background frame in black and a white outline with rounded edge. I can't believe it has not been done before.

```
app.setStyleSheet("QToolTip {
font-size:9pt;
color:white; padding:2px;
border-width:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-radius:20px;
background-color: black;
border: 1px solid white;}")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to set a custom [mask](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask) on tooltip widget. I can think of two ways of doing that:

- Implement an own [QStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstyle.html) with a mask returned for [QStyle::SH_ToolTip_Mask](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstyle.html#StyleHint-enum) style hint. That is a generic way as default QToolTip would use this mask ([example](https://github.com/QtCurve/qtcurve-qt5/blob/master/qt5/style/qtcurve_api.cpp#L1924)).
- Create a custom QToolTip based class with a proper mask and then use [QHelpEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qhelpevent.html) ([QEvent::ToolTip](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum)) event of your widget to show it. It's not a generic solution as it requires to filter events on all widgets which need custom tooltip.

Comment: `border-radius:5px;` still doesn't make it look good since it only rounds an outline and not the QToolTip's frame. The frame itself is unaffected by `border-radius:20px;` and it keeps its borders sharp.

Comment: @Sputnix, I misread your question. I've updated my answer with the ways of achieving what you want.

Comment: Thanks! The `QStyle` could be a probable solution. But the example is written in C++. And it is 50 pages long. I can't dedicate three days just to make the corners round. I will leave it as is. Not a big deal.