# How to make Qtooltip corner round in pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qtooltip

How to make Qtooltip corner round in pyqt5. Tried many stylesheet but it does not work. The frame on Qtooltip remains same.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible code snippet

Answer (score 2):

Qt Style Sheets cannot set the *mask* of a widget, which is what is required to change the shape of top level widgets to a different one than standard rectangles.

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920921) question has a partial answer, it's quite old and doesn't explain how to properly use the style hint and implement the style.

The solution is based on a [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) that updates the returnData of `styleHint()` by creating a proper mask based on the contents.

The biggest issue here is that there is absolutely **no way** to know the QSS properties used by a widget (and accessing the widget's `styleSheet()` is pointless, since style sheets can be inherited): we can never know if a widget has a border, and the possible radius of that border.

There is a way, though: we could locally render the tooltip on a QImage, and use [`createHeuristicMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#createHeuristicMask) to get a possible mask based on the contents, which should be set using the application stylesheets.

If, for some reason, the mask is still the full rectangle of the widget, we can "guess" a standard rounded mask anyway.

Note that the `returnData` of `styleHint()` is a [QStyleHintReturn](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylehintreturn.html), while we need a [QStyleHintReturnMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylehintreturnmask.html) because we must be able to write its `region`; in order to achieve this, we use the `cast()` function of the `sip` module (usually installed along with PyQt).

The following uses the default palette colors for the tooltip style sheet, but the important aspect is that the border *must* be slightly different than the background (otherwise the above mask creation won't work).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sip

class ProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def styleHint(self, hint, opt=None, widget=None, returnData=None):
        if hint == self.SH_ToolTip_Mask and widget:
            if super().styleHint(hint, opt, widget, returnData):
                # the style already creates a mask
                return True
            returnData = sip.cast(returnData, QtWidgets.QStyleHintReturnMask)
            src = QtGui.QImage(widget.size(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            src.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
            widget.render(src)

            mask = QtGui.QRegion(QtGui.QBitmap.fromImage(
                src.createHeuristicMask()))
            if mask == QtGui.QRegion(opt.rect.adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1)):
                # if the stylesheet doesn't set a border radius, create one
                x, y, w, h = opt.rect.getRect()
                mask = QtGui.QRegion(x + 4, y, w - 8, h)
                mask += QtGui.QRegion(x, y + 4, w, h - 8)
                mask += QtGui.QRegion(x + 2, y + 1, w - 4, h - 2)
                mask += QtGui.QRegion(x + 1, y + 2, w - 2, h - 4)

            returnData.region = mask
            return 1
        return super().styleHint(hint, opt, widget, returnData)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
app.setStyle(ProxyStyle())
palette = app.palette()
app.setStyleSheet('''
    QToolTip {{
        color: {fgd};
        background: {bgd};
        border: 1px solid {border};
        border-radius: 4px;
    }}
'''.format(
    fgd=palette.color(palette.ToolTipText).name(), 
    bgd=palette.color(palette.ToolTipBase).name(), 
    border=palette.color(palette.ToolTipBase).darker(110).name()
))
test = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Hover me', toolTip='Tool tip')
test.show()
app.exec()
```

Be aware, though, that this is not very optimal, because it involves rendering the tooltip every time it's being shown/resized: if your program shows many tooltips or updates them very frequently, performance can become poor. The alternative is to completely skip the heuristic mask creation and just set a predefined and default mask based on the contents, as shown near the end of the `styleHint()` override above.

Comment: This is great answer thanks!
I've also tweaked it a little bit...
```
            QStyleHintReturnMask *maskReturnData = qstyleoption_cast<QStyleHintReturnMask *>(returnData);
            QPainterPath path;
            path.addRoundedRect(option->rect, 10, 10);
            QRegion mask2(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());
            maskReturnData->region = mask2;
```
Using QpainterPath to create "smoother" result.

Comment: @Dariusz actually, that doesn't create a "smoother" result, it just allows creating corners with bigger radii, but they are not *really* smooth, because masking is always pixel based. The reason I used simple rectangular regions is because the default behavior has narrow corners which makes the computation of QPainterPath curves  pointless due to the little difference in pixels; it's also exactly what Qt does under the hood (if the underlying style hint uses rounded corners)